# CSS code not working in Firefox and IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox

I am trying to create a wiggle movement using CSS code. The code works fine in Chrome but not in Firefox and IE. The code that is working is:

```
@-webkit-keyframes spaceboots {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(0deg);
    }
    10% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg);
    }
    20% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg);
    }
    30% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 2px) rotate(0deg);
    }
    40% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg);
    }
    60% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg);
    }
    70% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(-1deg);
    }
    80% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg);
    }
    90% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 2px) rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg);
    }
}
.shake:hover, .shake:focus {
    -webkit-animation-name: spaceboots;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.8s;
    -webkit-transform-origin:50% 50%;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

It effects the following div tags. One of them is given here:

```
<form action="http://www.ahtcsonline.com/descriptions-tracs.html" target="_blank" onclick="window.open('http://www.ahtcsonline.com/descriptions-tracs.html','popup','width=650,height=600,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,directories=no,location=no,menubar=no,status=no,left=0,top=0'); return false">
<div class="c3">
<p class="Title"><a href="descriptions-tracs.html" target="_parent" title="Register for our Online TRACS Class"><img src="images/TRACS Page.png" alt="TRACS 202D" name="TRACS" width="87" height="104" border="0" align="top" class="shake" id="TRACS" ></a></p>
</div>
</form>
```

The above code works fine in Chrome but on any other browser. Through searching I found out that for Firefox and other browsers I have to change some syntax and so I added the following code along with the previous code (the following was made only for Firefox) but it still does not work.

```
    @-webkit-keyframes spaceboots {
0% { -moz-transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
10% { -moz-transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
20% { -moz-transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg); }
30% { -moz-transform: translate(0px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
40% { -moz-transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }
50% { -moz-transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg); }
60% { -moz-transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
70% { -moz-transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(-1deg); }
80% { -moz-transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }
90% { -moz-transform: translate(2px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
100% { -moz-transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
}
.shake:hover,
.shake:focus {
-moz-animation-name: spaceboots;
-moz-animation-duration: 0.8s;
-moz-transform-origin:50% 50%;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
.shake {
display:inline-block
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need, tested on both Chrome, Firefox, IE, Opera and Safari ([demo](http://jsbin.com/huxibolonu/3/edit?html,css,output)) :

```
@-webkit-keyframes spaceboots {
    0% { -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(0deg); /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */ }
    10% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */ }
    20% { -webkit-transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg); /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */ }
    30% { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 2px) rotate(0deg); /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */ }
    40% { -webkit-transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */ }
    50% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg); /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */ }
    60% { -webkit-transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg); /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */ }
    70% { -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(-1deg); /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */ }
    80% { -webkit-transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */ }
    90% { -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 2px) rotate(0deg); /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */ }
    100% { -webkit-transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */ }
}
@-moz-keyframes spaceboots {
    0% { transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(0deg); /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */ }
    10% { transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */ }
    20% { transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg); /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */ }
    30% { transform: translate(0px, 2px) rotate(0deg); /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */ }
    40% { transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */ }
    50% { transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg); /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */ }
    60% { transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg); /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */ }
    70% { transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(-1deg); /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */ }
    80% { transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */ }
    90% { transform: translate(2px, 2px) rotate(0deg); /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */ }
    100% { transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */ }
}
@-ms-keyframes spaceboots {
    0% { -ms-transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(0deg); /* IE 9 */ }
    10% { -ms-transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); /* IE 9 */ }
    20% { -ms-transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg); /* IE 9 */ }
    30% { -ms-transform: translate(0px, 2px) rotate(0deg); /* IE 9 */ }
    40% { -ms-transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); /* IE 9 */ }
    50% { -ms-transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg); /* IE 9 */ }
    60% { -ms-transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg); /* IE 9 */ }
    70% { -ms-transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(-1deg); /* IE 9 */ }
    80% { -ms-transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); /* IE 9 */ }
    90% { -ms-transform: translate(2px, 2px) rotate(0deg); /* IE 9 */ }
    100% { -ms-transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); /* IE 9 */ }
}
@-o-keyframes spaceboots {
    0% { transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(0deg); /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */ }
    10% { transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */ }
    20% { transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg); /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */ }
    30% { transform: translate(0px, 2px) rotate(0deg); /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */ }
    40% { transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */ }
    50% { transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg); /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */ }
    60% { transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg); /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */ }
    70% { transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(-1deg); /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */ }
    80% { transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */ }
    90% { transform: translate(2px, 2px) rotate(0deg); /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */ }
    100% { transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */ }
}
@keyframes spaceboots {
    0% { transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(0deg); /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */ }
    10% { transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */ }
    20% { transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg); /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */ }
    30% { transform: translate(0px, 2px) rotate(0deg); /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */ }
    40% { transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */ }
    50% { transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg); /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */ }
    60% { transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg); /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */ }
    70% { transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(-1deg); /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */ }
    80% { transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */ }
    90% { transform: translate(2px, 2px) rotate(0deg); /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */ }
    100% { transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */ }
}
.shake:hover,
.shake:focus {
    -webkit-animation: spaceboots 0.8s infinite; /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 5+ */
    animation: spaceboots 0.8s infinite; /* Chrome, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
    transform-origin:50% 50%;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to vendor prefix everything in order to make this work properly. Using a Mixin in SASS or SCSS would help eliminate a lot of the extraneous code.

If you are using SASS with Compass you could do it like this:

```
@import "compass/css3/transform"

@include translate($translate-x, $translate-y, $perspective, $only3d) {
//Insert values here
}
```

This would then export everything to CSS with all vendor prefixes.

Let me know if you need anything else.

Sources:
http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/transform/#mixin-translate

http://sass-lang.com/